# Connection to OPENVPN using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, openvpn

I'm creating a VPN Client, with Ikve2 and openvpn when comes to IKV2 its straight forward but whereas OPENVPN I had really hard time dealing with OVPN files, as i'm using FREERadius as authentication how can I pass username and password? I already tried connecting through
user-locked profile.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [FreeRadius .net Code here](https://github.com/frontporch/Radius.NET/blob/master/ClientTest/Program.cs)

```
//args = new string[4];
//args[0] = "192.168.1.1";
//args[1] = "secret";
//args[2] = "username";
//args[3] = "password";
```

```
RadiusClient rc = new RadiusClient(args[0], args[1]);
// Use username/password here
RadiusPacket authPacket = rc.Authenticate(args[2], args[3]);
authPacket.SetAttribute(new VendorSpecificAttribute(10135, 1, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Testing")));
authPacket.SetAttribute(new VendorSpecificAttribute(10135, 2, new[] { (byte)7 }));
RadiusPacket receivedPacket = await rc.SendAndReceivePacket(authPacket);
```